# HLF 1.4 multiple user Gateway?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Should an app have a single Gateway for all users and switch to the relevant identity for requests, or multiple Gateways (one per user) with identity initially set and never changed?

Should the Gateway be connected and disconnected after each request, or should it be initially connected once and left open?

Answer (score 3):

The following applies to v1.4 of the node implementation of Gateway in the fabric-network package.

You should have a single gateway for each individual user. Once you disconnect a gateway you should not use it again (ie don't attempt to call connect again).

A basic pattern for multi-user apps that are long running would be to create a gateway for each user and cache it. Use a stale policy to disconnect and disgard that gateway if it hasn't been used for a while by the user.